# Automatically drop down volume when earphones plugged in?

Tags: windows-8, laptop, audio, drivers

In my old Dell laptop, running Windows 7, whenever I would plug an earphone in, the volume automatically drops down to what I have set in the past when the earphones were plugged in. The volume again goes back to the last set level when the earphones weren't plugged in after I unplug  the earphones.

This isn't happening with my new Acer laptop, running Windows 8. Is it a Windows 8 bug or does it have to do anything with the drivers?

Comment: It's a driver's feature. Some drivers can detect audio jack plugged in  or provide separate output devices for jack and built-in speakers.

Comment: Have you got any suggestions on how to get such driver for my laptop, Acer Aspire V3-571G?

Comment: My driver does detect when an earphone is plugged in. It is just not adjusting the volume level automatically.

Comment: If the latest driver for your sound card doesn't have this feature, then you have to look for another solution. Maybe there's some program that provides this feature, but I haven't heard of one.